# How to print formatted labels from c#

Tags: c#, formatting, reporting

I'm writing a program that will (among other things) print out labels with variable information.  I want to be able to format these labels (preferably in a GUI) at design-time, then have them print out at runtime.  What tools/languages/projects can I use to accomplish this?

The label needs to include text and also Code39 or Code128 barcodes.

Printing will be done on a normal default printer, or possibly a label printer, unknown at this time.

Preference is for open-source, free projects, but any suggestions are appreciated.  I'd also like to be able to distribute the program through xcopy, meaning no separate installations needed on the client.

**EDIT: I'm now trying to do this using Microsoft Reporting services in local mode, but I'm still having problems getting the barcode to be readable.**

Comment: This sounds like a job for any of the myriad word processing / document editing tools that already exist.  Is there any reason why you want to reinvent such a complicated wheel?

Comment: @chomp -I don't think you understand what I'm looking for.  I need to be able to design the label, the end-user does NOT.

Comment: You need to clarify your question then, because right now it still sounds like a job for a PDF or similar file.  What requirements does this hypothetical software have that cannot be met by transmitting a plain old document for someone to print?

Comment: @chomp -Printed label needs to include formatting and also barcodes.  And if PDF can be used, how about a link to a tutorial?  Lets be constructive here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Microsoft Reporting Services I can use a local report.  Its not xcopy, but it is free and relatively easy.  I just have to install report viewer on the client (and the barcode font), then I can even run the .exe from a network share.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple walkthrough of using our programmable ActiveReports product to do this [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?arWLKAddressLabels.html). Once you design the labels you can get them in PDF or print them directly (among other things). Another example of using ActiveReports to create a label maker program is [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1588). That one uses the ActiveX/COM edition of ActiveReports but the concepts are still the same in the C#/.NET version.

We also provide a product named [Data Dynamics Reports](http://www.datadynamics.com/DataDynamicsReports) that uses a page-based metaphore for designing reports rather than the banded metephore like ActiveReports. It includes a label wizard which you can find out more about at [this link](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ddReports/webframe.html?ddrconLabelWizard.html).

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity inc.
```

Comment: -Looks like this would do what I need, but is perhaps overkill for my needs.  Will definitely keep it in mind.